# What's the difference between "really" and "for real"?

Tags: differences, exclamations

For example:

- I don't know who Tiger Woods is.
- For real?

and

- I don't know who Tiger Woods is.
- Really?

I don't see any difference in this case, but are there some specific cases when these exclamations are different?

Comment: General reference. There's no difference in *meaning* - it's just that *"For real?"* is still somewhat "slangier".

Comment: On <a href="http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for%20real">urbandictionary.com </a> there are some cases of 'for real' that you can see.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: a difference in connotation/usage is still a difference, and it's often precisely that sort of difference that *isn't* found in a dictionary. Therefore, by your very own reasoning, this is not general reference.

Comment: @Martha: Point taken. A difference is a difference is a difference. But it still seems to me it's general reference that these kind of "cut-down" responses aren't really "grammatical". Do we really want endless questions asking about the difference between, say, *"You can be sure of that!"* and the more common cut-down version *Sure!*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning - it's just that *"For real?"* is still somewhat *"slangier"*.

Note that it's easy to see *"Really?"* as a shortened version of grammatically sound constructions such as *"Is that **really** true?"*, whereas to me at least there's no obviously valid construction underpinning *"For real?"*.